# While viewing rendering attached to an item in Core DB, Sitecore is throwing server error

Tags: presentation, speak, sublayout

I am trying to access the details of a rendering attached to an item in the Core database, but Sitecore is throwing server error. Please refer to the attached screenshot.

[image: Item which I am trying to access]

[image: Error]

Comment: You need to use Sitecore Rocks for editing Sitecore core application presentation details.

Comment: @MarekMusielak The item I want to edit belongs to a Sitecore Module called EZImporter. Okay, let me try Sitecore Rocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@MarekMusielak mentions in his comment](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17970/while-viewing-rendering-attached-to-an-item-in-core-db-sitecore-is-throwing-ser/17979#comment26971_17970), you will need to use [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks) to edit the presentation details of core database items.

### Open an item's presentation details

[image: core database context menu in Sitecore Rocks]

### Edit the presentation details

[image: presentation details in Sitecore Rocks]

[image: properties of a presentation component in Sitecore Rocks]